# Dynamically find tables with primary keys

Tags: mysql

I need a script that will help me find tables that have primary keys, without specifying database name or table name.

Comment: maybe interesting? [Understanding the MySQL Information Schema Database](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/understanding-the-mysql-information-schema-database.html). Also: [Chapter 22 INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html), imo,  you just write SQL queries to find out what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    t.table_schema,t.table_name
from 
    information_schema.tables t 
    inner join information_schema .columns c  
        on t.table_schema=c.table_schema and t.table_name=c.table_name 
group by 
    t.table_schema,t.table_name   
having 
    sum(if(column_key in ('PRI','UNI'), 1,0)) =1;
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, there's always a constraint named "PRIMARY" for every primary key. So it's very simple to find them:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY';
```